# FInd mode of Poisson distribution with SymPy

Tags: sympy, distribution, poisson

Why I can't find the value at the mode of the Poisson pdf?

```
import sympy
from sympy import Symbol, simplify
from sympy.stats import Poisson, density

nobs = Symbol('nobs', positive=True, domain=sympy.Integers)
mu = Symbol('μ', domain=sympy.Reals, positive=True)
poisson_pdf = lambda n, _lambda: density(Poisson('X', _lambda))(n)
simplify(sympy.calculus.util.maximum(poisson_pdf(nobs, mu), mu))
```

I get

```
Max(oo*(-1)**nobs, (nobs*exp(-1))**nobs/gamma(nobs + 1))
```

the second argument of max is the solution I would like. What am I missing? And Why I get a gamma function if nobs is positive integer?

Answer (score 1):

1. The mode of a Poisson is not always unique.  (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#/media/File:Poisson_pmf.svg), note the modes on the plots for λ = 1 and λ = 4.)
2. [Gamma(n + 1) == factorial(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#The_gamma_and_pi_functions) for positive integer n.

Comment: my `n` is positive integer: `nobs = Symbol('nobs', positive=True, domain=sympy.Integers)`

Comment: right, the mode is non-unique when the parameter is integer. By the way if I simplify the result from sympy I get +oo for nobs even, which doesn't make sense, no?

Comment: Yes, your `n` **is** a positive integer, hence that gamma function that bothers you **is** a factorial.

Comment: I'm not a Python/SymPy user, so my answer was based on the fact that it was reporting the max of two terms.  My bad, I have since looked up and found that `oo` is infinity in SymPy, and you're right, that makes no sense for even numbers.  Looks like a bug.  The good news is that if you want the mode of a Poisson with rate lambda, it's `ceiling(lambda)` or `floor(lambda + 1)` -- no need to use SymPy.